# Favicon Best Practices

Tags: favicon, android, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Favicon, icon, shortcut icon, apple-touch-icon: Are there any others?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2010/favicon-icon-shortcut-icon-apple-touch-icon-are-there-any-others)

This is a two part question:

The first is about favicons in general. Are there any good practices to follow when it comes to these icons? Currently my site had `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://mysite.com/favicon.ico" />` in the `<head>` of my site pages and I have the file `favicon.ico` in my root folder to cover the basics. Are there other practies that are not as well known yet good when creating/using  a favicon? IS 16x16 still the best size?

Th second part of this question is about other "favicons" on the site. The main one I mention is the Apple's "favicon" for my site. I can put this code: `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="somepath/image.png" />` onto my site and when a person using an iOS operating system adds my site to their homescreen it views my icon vs a thumbnail of my site. Do other devices/operating systems have anything similar?  (Android, Windows Mobile, Symbian, Blackberry, etc.)

Are there other things I should know?

Note: [This Question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2010/favicon-icon-shortcut-icon-apple-touch-icon-are-there-any-others) comes close to answering this but it is over a year old and much has changed in that time at least in relation to phones/tablets.

Comment: If much has changed since that previous question(I disagree completely, BTW), that's what you should be asking about directly, not just referencing in passing; most of this is re-hash. Honestly, very little's changed about specifying favicons since they were first implemented, never mind the past year. There's just not that much to change. As far as the 16x16 bit: yes, it's still the size commonly used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

16x16 is still best practice, this isn't something that is likely to change soon.

To answer your second question;

Mobile devices that try and include an image for a bookmark or website generally use the favicon.  I can't speak for them all but certainly the ones you mentioned there don't have any special icon type or setting.